# Foreigners Marriage in France

Tags: france, marriage

I wanted to ask you some help for marriage. I live in France with a visa Scientifique Chercheur which is soon going to expire on 19 September 2016. Before it expires, I'm going to submit my document to prefecture to renew it for the next year to get a carte de sejour which is surely going to be renewed. I want to marry my girlfriend; she is from Mauritius. I don't want to return to Mauritius and come back again as this is very expensive, a round-trip ticket costs at least 1500 euros for one person. So, I want to marry in France itself, and I have the following question:

1. Is this possible?
2. Do I have to wait to get my new carte de sejour
       before marrying?
3. Will my girlfriend allowed to come here in France
       for marriage?

Thanks